# How to add Magnet links in the Deluge WebUI?

Tags: bittorrent, deluge

When adding a torrent in the Deluge WebUI, the Infohash button is disabled. How do I enable this function or what is the solution to add magnet links?

Comment: It would be nice if the latest version of Deluge, 1.3.4, was added to either the unofficial repo or the ubuntu repo

Answer (score 6):

From Deluge [1.3.4](https://launchpad.net/~deluge-team/+archive/ppa) onwards there is now support for Magnet URIs in the **Add Url** box of the WebUI.

For reference, the Infohash option is only for the [BitTorrent hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_BitTorrent_terms#Hash) so it is different to a [Magnet Uri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme) that is a link that contains a Base32 encoded version of this hash along with other information such as trackers and filename. For 1.3.5 I have hidden this unused button to prevent any further confusion.